# Getting street view image with LatLng on Google API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I want to get a image which is from Google Street View with LatLng information.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

I read almost contents in the documents Google serves, but I couldn't find the option I want.

Is there anything else that I would take a thing as reference?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm going to read it. @Tiny Giant

Comment: Do you want the Street View looking at that LatLng?  Looking from that LatLng in a particular direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a pair of good example from google   [sample1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview)
and [sample2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple) Whit this is not difficult build a proper web page and contain all the relevant information for a good start

The code for sample2

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Street View service</title>
      <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }

      </style>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
      <script>
  function initialize() {
    var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573, -71.098326);
    var mapOptions = {
      center: fenway,
      zoom: 14
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var panoramaOptions = {
      position: fenway,
      pov: {
        heading: 34,
        pitch: 10
      }
    };
    var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
    map.setStreetView(panorama);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 45%; height: 100%;float:left"></div>
      <div id="pano" style="width: 45%; height: 100%;float:left"></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

or the simplest embedded access  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,-73.988354&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10

all from google.